# My Bluetooth-enabled Android app doesn't work

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I'm working on a project to do a Bluetooth-enabled Android app.

My app doesn't work! There's a pop-up block, saying *Unfortunately, Bluetooth led (my app name) has stopped*, and I'm back to the widget screen again.
Would it be a problem at my XML file for manifest?

my layout XML codes:

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonON"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="Turn LED On" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonOFF"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="Turn LED Off" />
```

Comment: No error in code != no problems on real hardware.  It would be beneficial for all of us if you were able to narrow down what you think it may be, then post the relevant code associated with that.

Answer (score 0):

The most common answer to this is that you are performing a task in your thread that takes too much time, as consequence the task results unresponsive and the application is killed because of this. The possible solutions are:

1. improving the business logic of your application
2. do your task in a separate thread
3. adopt an async approach

Comment: You need to check your logcat - I bet there is an error there.

I frequently forget to add the Activity to the manifest when I create it the first time.

Comment: @Booger if an application is stopped this means that at least it was running for an undefined period of time, and if it was running the manifest is probably fine.